# Send String Safetly from mobile device to C# Server

Tags: security, encryption, sniffer

My App Send to my server User's Facebook Access Token / password.

```
$.ajax { url:'http://www.mysite.com?accesstoken=**** / pass=**** ....
```

I know that a sniffers threat would make it dangoures. Is that any code\tool to send the data encryption (without https)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because there is no other way to establish trust in the JavaScript code send from the server. You could send authenticated JavaScript, but you would need something on the client to verify the code.

Comment: so what is the best way to do what I need?

Comment: None, you really need pre-established trust, in this case only SSL would suffice. Java also has a trust store, but requiring signed Java applets is a test and configuration nightmare.